# How can I import SVN with inconsistent branching structure into Git?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, git-branch, git-clone

I apologize if this question has been asked before, but my case is a relatively specific one.  I have been at my company for some time and using SVN, but desired recently to move to Git, for various reasons.

The issue I'm having right now is that my company uses a non-standard branching structure, and unfortunately, at times in the past, it hasn't even been a consistent non-standard branching structure.

The history I'm aware of, since joining the company, is that we use one main trunk branch, from which we create release branches and feature branches.  The structure of these branches isn't simply a standard trunk/branches/tags structure, however.  We have several subfolders for different types of branches.  For instance, release branches go in branches_release, feature branches in branches_feature, etc, like the following:

```
branches_feature/featureA
branches_release/2.0
```

I figured out how to make this clone/fetch work properly by modifying the Git repo's config so that

```
branches = {branches_feature,branches_release}/*:refs/remotes/branches/*
```

This has been relatively successful in fetching the appropriate branches.  The one issue I'm having is that when my company first started, it used a structure more like:

```
branches_feature/username/branchname
```

Unfortunately to find this out (the hard way) I had to "git svn fetch" and find that all of these branches following the older branching convention have been collapsed so that in Git each user has a single branch in which exists every branch made.  So,

```
branches_feature/username/featureA
branches_feature/username/featureB
```

have been collapsed into:

```
branches_feature/username
```

Obviously this is insufficient for a properly reproduced SVN repo history, but I'm not sure how to modify the config's branches line to encapsulate all of these branches AND still use the new branching format properly.  I've been trying to manipulate it in various ways, but I wind up either getting errors or simply being unsuccessful in my attempts.

If anyone can suggest a good way to appropriately preserve the SVN repo's history while importing from SVN to Git, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**: For anything except the most trivial of repositories, you'll never be able to fully preserve the contents of a Subversion repository in a `git svn` repository.

I'm adapting this from [my answer to a similar question](/a/9502677/220155).

By my understanding, your Subversion tree looks something like this, where `*` indicates a folder that at some point in the Subversion history would have been the root of a working copy:

```
/
|--branches_feature/
|  |--featureA/       *
|  |--userB/          *
|  |  |--featureB/    * (Possibly now deleted, but existed previously)
|  |  `--featureC/    *
|  `--userC/          *
|--branches_release/
|  |--V1.0/           *
|  `--V2.0/           *
`trunk/               *
```

Sadly, `git svn` can't cope with a repository like that in a particularly sensible way. You're not going to get a Git repository that has all the branches of your Subversion repository and none that it shouldn't have.

Your options are thus:

- Treat both the `branches_feature` and `branches_feature/userB` as branch folders.

  You'll end up with some Git branches that, were you to check them out, would give you a bunch of folders each containing a Subversion branch folder, and `git svn fetch` operations on those folders may take longer, as the fetch will need to be done for both the container branch and the real branch.    Because Git is clever, it at least will take up exceedingly little extra disk space.

  I'd expect your `.git/config` to have lines like the below:

  ```
  branches = branches_feature/*:refs/remotes/branches/*
  branches = branches_feature/userB/*:refs/remotes/branches/*
  branches = branches_release/*:refs/remotes/branches/*
  ```
- Ignore some branch folders. Just don't tell `git svn` about them, and continue in merry ignorance.
- Pick out the branches you're interested in, and pick them up manually. If you want the `userB` folder, you'll still need to be careful about the history you pick up, though, if its sub-branches have been deleted and you don't want to pick them up.

  Here, I'd expect your `.git/config` to have a whole load of lines like the below:

  ```
  fetch = branches_feature/featureA:refs/remotes/branches/featureA
  fetch = branches_feature/userB/featureB:refs/remotes/branches/featureB
  fetch = branches_feature/userC:refs/remotes/branches/userC
  ```
- Patch your version of `git svn` to somehow allow it to cope with this scenario. Bonus points if you get it included in future official Git releases.

Comment: Certainly not doing any git svn patching (yet).  My plan currently is to do something like branches = branches_feature/{userA,userB}/*:refs/remotes/branches_feature/*.  (Like your first solution)  My concern is whether it will try to create two branches, one for "userA" AND one for "userA/feature", if I use this method.  I'm a little afraid to start, given this uncertainty...lol.  I'll have to eventually though I guess...

Comment: Just like that, it won't; `svn-remote.branches` only creates branches for the subdirectories. Compare with the "standard" config of `branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/branches/*`—you don't get a branch called "branches" there, only a branch for each subdirectory.

Comment: Also, feel free to experiment! If you don't like the result, remove the relevant lines from your config file, and delete the files/folders you want to remove from `.git/logs/refs/remotes`, `.git/refs/remotes` and `.git/svn/refs/remotes`.

Comment: Well what I meant was using that in addition.  I would need to do a branches line for both branches_feature/* AND branches_feature/{userA,userB}/*.  And I imagine that has the potential to create the undesirable situation of duplicated (sort of) branches.  I really need a way to EXCLUDE branches_feature/{userA,userB} while INCLUDING branches_feature/{userA,userB}/* AND branches_feature/*.  Time to start experimenting, I guess!

Comment: I think that's the option that `git svn` just doesn't support. Sadly. Do let us know if you find a way to do it, though!

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly handle this, but you should consider how much effort you're willing to put in compared with the return.

If you just limited your conversion to release branches and the trunk, would the absence of feature branches be a major issue? You should still have the commits (because they'll appear on merge) so the only commits that won't be present are those that haven't been merged back to the trunk.

If necessary, you can convert the feature branches you need individually later, and graft them into place with `git replace` and `git filter-branch`.

Comment: The issue here is that I'm trying to entirely replace the SVN repository (if I can).  For a personal workflow, and even for the company currently, release branches and trunk would be sufficient.  However, we would not be able to kill off the old SVN repo due to not having the previous history.  I will be sure not to rule that out as an option, however.  Much appreciated.

Comment: Quite understand, and I've taken a lot of effort to migrate everything in previous migrations, but I've almost never used it. You might find a `svn sync` of the existing repo, tarballed (or exported with `svnadmin dump` and compressed) and backed-up somewhere safeguards your history without bringing all the feature-branch baggage with you. Your other option is to individually pull the feature branches you need like @me_and suggests. The main thing to remember - SVN isn't going anywhere, so as long as you do a backup, you can always go back later an import what you need.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too concerned about the (older) history, for myself.  I'm trying to convince my company to make the switch from SVN to Git, and I feel that the bigger issue for them would be fragmenting the history from the present.  Being able to structure the history appropriately would simply make my argument a bit easier.  Managers don't make things easier (or simpler) than they have to be, sometimes...haha.